# Influxdb database names with space creating issues

Tags: influxdb, influxql

- There are some databases created inside my influxdb and the names of the databases have space in-between.
- I can't able to use those databases using the CLI command `use <database name>` and hence I can't able to see any series out of it.
- I have tried other approaches like using special symbols such as `\, [, etc.` but all those didn't work
- Please provide some olutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As influxdb format you cant include it, cause it will replace " " to "", influxdb need exactly sintax, and whitespace its key value.
Look that https://github.com/tihomir-kit/InfluxData.Net/issues/49